# Flash cs5 - how to change frame rate of only movie clip?

Tags: flash, fla

I am building a small flash application. 
In my application I've inserted an fla video.
the flv video's length when I open it in vlc player is 16 seconds (after I edit the speed of the video in an external program and then converted it back to fla).
When I open it in flash cs 5, the video's length is back to 90 seconds.

I guess it's got something to do with the frame rate of my flash project.
I'd like to be able to change the frame rate of only the movie clip containing that video, and not of the entire stage. How is that possible?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

FLV videos should not be affected by the frame rate you set for your movie.  Perhaps your library still contains the old version of the FLV? Just open the properties panel for your FLV and update the asset.

Comment: I did, it doesn't work. Do you know how I can set the frame rate?

Comment: It is like this: Your video will always have its original length, no matter what framerate you set the FLA to.  So if you want to change the length of the video, you have to re-encode the original video file.  Just to clarify: Is it correct that you have a FLV video imported into a FLA document?  If so, then you can re-encode your FLV in Adobe Media Encoder and update the asset in the library.